# How to do filter on nested array of object in more than two level

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a nested array of objects, I'm trying to filter the given array of objects using a property from the third level of its array property value. For example, from the below array I like to filter the entire array using the property `"state" = "NY"`.

```
organisation = [
   {
      "dept_id":1,
      "dept":{
         "name":"finance",
         "employees":[
            {
               "emp_id":1,
               "name":"John",
               "address":[
                  {
                     "country":"US",
                     "state":"NC"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   {
      "dept_id":2,
      "dept":{
         "name":"marketing",
         "employees":[
            {
               "emp_id":2,
               "name":"David",
               "address":[
                  {
                     "country":"US",
                     "state":"NY"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   {
      "dept_id":3,
      "dept":{
         "name":"sales",
         "employees":[
            {
               "emp_id":3,
               "name":"Robert",
               "address":[
                  {
                     "country":"US",
                     "state":"NC"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

As a result of using the filter `"state":"NY"` my expected answer is

```
organisation = [
   {
      "dept_id":2,
      "dept":{
         "name":"marketing",
         "employees":[
            {
               "emp_id":2,
               "name":"David",
               "address":[
                  {
                     "country":"US",
                     "state":"NY"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

How can I use filter method using javascript to get this expected result.

Comment: `organisation.filter(o => o.dept.employees.some(e => e.address.some(a => a.state === 'NY')))`

Comment: Thanks abhishekkannojia it is working .. if you can add this as an answer that will be great for reference .. once again thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter`, `Array.prototype.some`, and `Array.prototype.find` functions for achieving your required outcome. Try this-

```js
const organisation=[{dept_id:1,dept:{name:"finance",employees:[{emp_id:1,name:"John",address:[{country:"US",state:"NC"}]}]}},{dept_id:2,dept:{name:"marketing",employees:[{emp_id:2,name:"David",address:[{country:"US",state:"NY"}]}]}},{dept_id:3,dept:{name:"sales",employees:[{emp_id:3,name:"Robert",address:[{country:"US",state:"NC"}]}]}}];

const filter = "NY";
const res = organisation.filter(
  item => item.dept.employees.some(
    employee => employee.address.find(address => address.state === filter)
  )
);

console.log(res);
```

Here, I've applied the `filter` on the `organization` array, then check if any employee inside the `employees` array has the `address` with the `state` value "**NY**".

Comment: Thanks Sajeeb i will test this and update here

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter` with combination of `Array.prototype.some` to filter out the results you want.

```js
const organisation=[{dept_id:1,dept:{name:"finance",employees:[{emp_id:1,name:"John",address:[{country:"US",state:"NC"}]}]}},{dept_id:2,dept:{name:"marketing",employees:[{emp_id:2,name:"David",address:[{country:"US",state:"NY"}]}]}},{dept_id:3,dept:{name:"sales",employees:[{emp_id:3,name:"Robert",address:[{country:"US",state:"NC"}]}]}}];
    
    const result = organisation.filter(
      item => item.dept.employees.some(
        employee => employee.address.some(address => address.state === 'NY')  // Filter condition
      )
    );
    
    console.log(result);
```

Basically this filters the `organization` array where some `empoloyee` has some `address` with `state` value `'NY'`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const organisation=[{dept_id:1,dept:{name:"finance",employees:[{emp_id:1,name:"John",address:[{country:"US",state:"NC"}]}]}},{dept_id:2,dept:{name:"marketing",employees:[{emp_id:2,name:"David",address:[{country:"US",state:"NY"}]}]}},{dept_id:3,dept:{name:"sales",employees:[{emp_id:3,name:"Robert",address:[{country:"US",state:"NC"}]}]}}];

const filter = "NY";
const res = organisation.filter(item => item.dept.employees.find(add => JSON.stringify(add.address).includes('"state":"' + filter + '"')));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use filter only if you want.

```
filtered = organisation.filter(el => el.dept.employees.filter(el => el.address.filter(el => el.state == 'NY').length > 0 ).length > 0);
```

```js
organisation = [
   {
      "dept_id":1,
      "dept":{
         "name":"finance",
         "employees":[
            {
               "emp_id":1,
               "name":"John",
               "address":[
                  {
                     "country":"US",
                     "state":"NC"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   {
      "dept_id":2,
      "dept":{
         "name":"marketing",
         "employees":[
            {
               "emp_id":2,
               "name":"David",
               "address":[
                  {
                     "country":"US",
                     "state":"NY"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   {
      "dept_id":3,
      "dept":{
         "name":"sales",
         "employees":[
            {
               "emp_id":3,
               "name":"Robert",
               "address":[
                  {
                     "country":"US",
                     "state":"NC"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   }
]


filtered = organisation.filter(el => el.dept.employees.filter(el => el.address.filter(el => el.state == 'NY').length > 0 ).length > 0);

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

I filtered it like this. Try this

```
    const filteredOrg = [];
    
    organisation.forEach((item) => {
       item.dept.employees.forEach((employe) => {
        employe.address.forEach((address) => {
          if (address.state === "NY") {
            filteredOrg.push(item);
          }
        });
      });

});
```

I hope it will work for you too.

Happy coding!